How do I find my new created txt folder using fstream in a project folder that Visual Studio created?
I am new to Visual Studio and I found out that for Visual Studio to compile the folder you need to create a project folder that creates it inside the user folder, now I used fstream to try to create a txt file and I can't find the txt file anywhere in the project folder inside the user folder, couldn't find any help on Google. Any help would be appreciated!
I tried to go through all the folders inside the project folder but with no luck.

I test and don't have this problem. Could you provide me with some of your code and the console output after running it?
